# What algorithm does arsort use?

Tags: php

The [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) doesnt seem to tell us what algorithm is used for array sorting. So what algorithm does the function arsort use? In otherwords, does it use merge sort, quick sort?

Code taken from doc:

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");
arsort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a = orange
d = lemon
b = banana
c = apple
```

Comment: Does it really matter, as long as it sorts correctly and quickly?  (sorting is one of those field where I would say: "if it ain't broke, don't fix it"). However, if I have to take a guess, it's probably quicksort, from the C library.

Comment: Manual :) http://php.net/sort has the hint.

Comment: @JvO: It's okay to ask about the language and how it works.

Comment: @JvO Its a function which is used frequently (at least by me). I was curious on how it works =p

Comment: @hakre, @goaler444; sure, no problem. Curiosity is good! Have fun poking inside the PHP source code ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all PHP sort functions, the quicksort algorithm is used

See the [Note in the manual](http://www.php.net/sort):

> **Note**: Like most PHP sorting functions, sort() uses an implementation of » Quicksort.